# Add mp3 codec to qt-project

Tags: qt, audio, codec, qt5

I am really new to Qt development as well as audio codecs. I recently found a way to play mp3 sound using QSound. I want to play it in my qt project using QAudioOutput, but there is no mp3 codec in QAudioDeviceInfo::supportedCodecs().

I tried install mp3 codec but it is still not listed in QAudioDeviceInfo::supportedCodecs(). How can I add a codec to QAudioDeviceInfo::supportedCodecs()?

Comment: which version of Qt are you using? `QtMultimedia` has changed a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition `QAudioDeviceInfo` provides an interface to query audio devices and their functionality. Which means any codec returned by `QAudioDeviceInfo::supportedCodecs()` is a codec format the device is able to play directly, and will be probably be raw audio format like `pcm`. On the other hand `mp3` need to go through a software decoder first, so It will not be in this list.

Take a look at the [Media Player example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-player-example.html) for a reference. It should be able to play mp3 and other formats. The project should be available in the Qt source or installation directory in your machine, either under the folder **demo** or **examples**.

It seems from the source that it does lot more than just barely playing audio. So focus on the constructor of the class `Player` as well as the method `Player::addToPlaylist()`

ps :I speak in conditional tense because I am more familiar with Qt 4 than Qt 5.

EDIT:

As long as windows media player cannot play mp3, you will not have full mp3 support in your Qt app, and the `Player` example I gave you will not work either. Download some codecs in your system till Windows media player can play mp3.

Comment: I've tried the class Player in the example. It cannot play mp3.

Comment: can you play mp3 in your system with another app?? Which OS are you using??

Comment: I can, using VLC player. I am using windows XP.

Comment: can you play using windows media player? vlc use its own codecs, not the one available on the system.

Comment: my windows media player can't play it. By the way I recently found the way to play mp3, using QSound. But I can't customize the settings using QSound, so I would like to ask if there is a way using QAudioOutput.

Comment: The [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimediawidgets-player.html) provide as sample is 404 not found.

Comment: @UmNyobe Maybe you should update the link to [this one](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-player-example.html) if I'm guessing it right?

Comment: I already made the update. Anyway it is not my fault if a link on the internet become invalid.